How to combine two files into one report?
I have two .dat files polnamei.dat as the primary and polfile.dat as the secondary and I am trying to combine them to make policy report.  The farthest I have managed is to make the headers populate, but never anything passed that.  I always come up with a error stating 'POLICY-IN' not numeric: \000\000\000\000\001\000 any help and a explanation would be extremely helpful!
  IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. example.
       Environment Division.
       Input-output section.
       file-control.

       select POLICYIN assign to 'C:\Cobol\polnamei.dat'
           ORGANIZATION is SEQUENTIAL.


       SELECT POLICYREPORT ASSIGN TO 'C:\Cobol\policyreport.txt'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

       SELECT POLICYFILE ASSIGN TO 'C:\Cobol\polfile.dat'
           ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL.

       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
      **** student file
       fd POLICYIN.
       01 POLNAMEIREC.
           03 POLICY-IN    PIC 9(6).
           03 FIRSTNAME-IN PIC X(15).
           03 LASTNAME-IN  PIC X(15).
           03 ADRESS-IN    PIC X(30).
           03 CITY-IN      PIC X(30).
           03 STATE-IN     PIC X(15).
           03 ZIP-IN       PIC X(9).
           03 PHONE-IN     PIC X(10).
           03 SSN-IN       PIC X(9).

       FD POLICYFILE.
       01 POLICYFILEREC.
           03 POLICY-FILE-IN     PIC 9(6).
           03 POLICYDATE-IN PIC X(10).
           03 PREMIUM-IN    PIC 9(6)V99.

       FD POLICYREPORT.
       01 POLICYREPORTREC PIC X(80).

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

       01 WS-KEY.
           03 POLICY-NUMBER PIC 9(6).
       01 WS-END-OF-JOB PIC X VALUE 'N'.

       01 DETAILLINE.
           03 POLICY-OUT       PIC 9(4).
           03 FIRSTNAME-OUT    PIC X(15).
           03 LASTNAME-OUT     PIC X(15).
           03 POLICYDATE-OUT   PIC X(10).
           03 PREMIUM-OUT      PIC 9(6)V99.

       01 WS-TOTAL-PREMIUM    PIC 9(8)V99 VALUE 0.

       01 WS-NEW-FIRSTNAME PIC X(15).
       01 WS-NEW-LASTNAME PIC X(15).

       01 WS-REPORTLINE.
           03 WS-REPORT-POLICY     PIC 9(4).
           03 WS-REPORT-FIRSTNAME  PIC X(15).
           03 WS-REPORT-LASTNAME   PIC X(15).
           03 WS-REPORT-POLICYDATE PIC X(10).
           03 WS-REPORT-PREMIUM    PIC 9(6)V99.

       01 LINCNT    PIC 99.
       01 WSDATE.
           03 YY PIC 99.
           03 MM PIC 99.
           03 DD PIC 99.
       01 PAGE-IN PIC 9999.

        01 HEADER1.
       05 MM-OUT PIC 99.
       05        PIC X VALUE "/".
       05 DD-OUT   PIC 99.
       05          PIC X VALUE  "/".
       05 YY-OUT   PIC 99.
       05          PIC X(30).
       05          PIC X(14)  VALUE "POLICY REPORT".
       05          PIC X(10).
       05          PIC X(5) VALUE "PAGE ".
       05 PAGE-OUT PIC  Z,ZZ9.
       05          PIC  X(10).
       05          PIC  X(13) VALUE "Casey Kinkade".

      ***************Line 2 of the report*********************
       01 HEADER2.
       10          PIC X(10).
       10          PIC  X(10) VALUE "POLICY ID".
       10          PIC  X(15) VALUE "FIRST NAME".
       10          PIC  X(15) VALUE "LAST NAME".
       10          PIC  X(10) VALUE "POL DATE".
       10          PIC  X(15) VALUE "PREMIUM".
      *******Procedure Division contains actual logic
       Procedure division.
       100-MAIN.
           PERFORM 200-OPEN.
           PERFORM UNTIL WS-END-OF-JOB = 'Y'
               PERFORM 300-GET-POLICY-NUMBER
               IF POLICY-NUMBER = 99
                   MOVE 'Y' TO WS-END-OF-JOB
               ELSE
                   PERFORM 400-READ-AND-DISPLAY
               END-IF
           END-PERFORM
           PERFORM 500-PRINT-TOTAL
           PERFORM 600-CLOSE.
           STOP RUN.

      **** In this module we will perform all of the housekeeping tasks
       200-OPEN.
           OPEN INPUT POLICYIN
           OPEN INPUT POLICYFILE
           OPEN OUTPUT POLICYREPORT
           ACCEPT WSDATE FROM DATE
           MOVE MM TO MM-OUT
           MOVE YY TO YY-OUT
           MOVE DD TO DD-OUT
           MOVE ZEROES TO LINCNT
           MOVE 1 TO PAGE-IN.
           *> DISPLAY 'THE MATRIX IS REAL'.

      ****** Read loop ********************
       300-GET-POLICY-NUMBER.
            READ POLICYIN
           AT END
            MOVE 'Y' TO WS-END-OF-JOB
            NOT AT END
            IF POLICY-IN IS NUMERIC
            MOVE POLICY-IN TO POLICY-NUMBER
            ELSE
              CONTINUE
            END-IF
           END-READ.



       400-READ-AND-DISPLAY.
           READ POLICYFILE
           AT END
        MOVE 'Y' TO WS-END-OF-JOB
         NOT AT END
        MOVE POLICY-IN TO POLICY-OUT
        MOVE FIRSTNAME-IN TO FIRSTNAME-OUT
        MOVE LASTNAME-IN TO LASTNAME-OUT
        MOVE POLICYDATE-IN TO POLICYDATE-OUT
        MOVE PREMIUM-IN TO PREMIUM-OUT

        ADD PREMIUM-IN TO WS-TOTAL-PREMIUM

        STRING
            POLICY-OUT DELIMITED BY SIZE
            ' ' DELIMITED BY SIZE
            FIRSTNAME-OUT DELIMITED BY SIZE
            ' ' DELIMITED BY SIZE
            LASTNAME-OUT DELIMITED BY SIZE
            ' ' DELIMITED BY SIZE
            POLICYDATE-OUT DELIMITED BY SIZE
            ' ' DELIMITED BY SIZE
            PREMIUM-OUT DELIMITED BY SIZE
        INTO POLICYREPORTREC

        WRITE POLICYREPORTREC AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.

        ADD 1 TO LINCNT.


       500-PRINT-TOTAL.
           MOVE 'TOTAL PREMIUM: ' TO POLICYREPORTREC
           STRING WS-TOTAL-PREMIUM DELIMITED BY SIZE
           INTO POLICYREPORTREC
           WRITE POLICYREPORTREC AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES.

       600-CLOSE.

           CLOSE POLICYIN.
           CLOSE POLICYFILE.
           CLOSE POLICYREPORT.
           *> DISPLAY 'FILE CLOSED.'.


tried to move and perform statements also random index with key and invalid logic

You have to do the work. Essentially you need to code an inner loop for every record in the first file to match records in the second file. Welcome to the 1970s.
These comprised most of the COBOL file handling programs of the period and were the source of numerous bugs!
For some education on how best to do this take a look at Jacksons structured programming tutorials of that period.
Jackson Structured programming tutorials

it would be fine to see some lines in both files to understand better the problem.
Meanwhile, the explanation is:
in your actual code, POLICY-NUMBER is getting value just when EOF is reached and POLICY-IN is numeric. Otherwise, the program will perform 400 paragraph (POLICE-NUMBER <> 99) and will raise an exception when moving POLICY-IN to POLICY-OUT if its not numeric.
You can discard the variable POLICY-NUMBER and test if WS-END-OF-JOB = Y after invoking 300 paragraph to decide performing 400 paragraph or not, but be aware you are using the same flag in both 300 and 400 paragraphs to control different files.
If your input file may contain non numeric values, you should test it before moving POLICY-IN to POLICY-OUT and decide if you will use it or advancing to next record.
In adittion, it seems you want to treat records in the second file (paragraph 400) until POLICY-FILE-IN gets a different value from POLICY-IN, but there is nothing in that way.

"POLICY-NUMBER is getting value just when EOF is reached and POLICY-IN is numeric" is incorrect. The program source has poor indentation. MOVE POLICY-IN TO POLICY-NUMBER occurs within a NOT AT END meaning every READ that is not EOF.

Thank you Rick Smith for you attentive eyes. You're right. The problem still remains: if POLICY-IN is not numeric then POLICY-NUMBER is not updated, and 400 paragraph will execute, trying to move POLICY-IN to POLICY-OUT and will fail.
